# Access GPS through watchOS 3

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-3

Apple Watch series 2 has build-in GPS. 
I'm looking at latest SDK, i didn't find any API for that function.

My question: 
Can I track my path during swimming ( without iPhone ), which API i should use?

Answer (score 3):

[Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation) is the correct way to do this. The watch will automatically determine whether the phone is connected or not, and switch between the built in GPS vs the phone based on connection.

Comment: If my phone is nearby, I'd rather start the tracking there and just report updates to the watch to display it. On a series 2 I'd ask the user where he wants to track? Phone or Watch. Is there a way to figure out if the watch I am currently running on even has a build in gps?

Comment: I'm afraid that there isn't a method of reliably determining whether you're on a watch with GPS, the only way that I'm aware to do this would be to either sniff out the device identifier (discouraged for obvious reasons) or do some combination of determining whether the phone is connected and whether core location is available (which is probably your best bet).